# How can I calculate the posterior mean of a two-point distribution?

Tags: distributions, bayesian

I am trying to reproduce some of the results in [this paper](http://openaccess.city.ac.uk/1612/1/Conservative_bounds_for_the_pfd.pdf).

Specifically, there is a two-point distribution with one probability mass concentrated at $pfd_A \times pfd_B$ and the other mass concentrated at $z_{AB}(N)$, where $z_{AB}(N)$ is the value of $z$ that maximizes this posterior mean:

$$F_{AB}(z) = ... = \frac{pfd_A pfd_B (1-pfd_A pfd_B)^N(1-d_{AB}(0))+z(1-z)^Nd_{AB}(0)}{(1-pfd_A pfd_B)^N(1-d_{AB}(0)) + (1-z)^Nd_{AB}(0)}$$

Given the following values (from Table 1 in [the paper](http://openaccess.city.ac.uk/1612/1/Conservative_bounds_for_the_pfd.pdf)):

- $pfd_{A}=10^{-4}$
- $pfd_{B}=10^{-3}$
- $d_{AB}(0) = 0.01$
- $N=1055$

I should get

- $z_{AB}(1055) = 1e-4$
- $F_{AB}(z_{AB}(1055)) = 9.999650e-7$

But, I don't. Instead, my calculations (which consist of simply maximizing the posterior mean as specified earlier) give:

- $z_{AB}(1055) = 0.000949577150390227$
- $F_{AB}(z_{AB}(1055)) = 3.604214e-6$.

If I understand correctly, this is where the latter probability mass is concentrated, but I don't know how to incorporate the former mass -- the one concentrated at $pfd_A \times pfd_B = 10^{-4} \times 10^{-3} = 10^{-7}$.

I apologize if this question is trivial -- I do not have a strong background in statistics.